# Converting Propel to JSON with linked entities

Tags: php, json, propel

I have this setup in a PHP project using Propel (which I'm new to).

> User: userid, firstname, lastname
>
> SignIn: signinid, userid, time

SignIn, in this case, is a table containing the times each user signed in.

What I want is to print out a JSON string using Propel of the last ten SignIn entries. On the front end I want to display something like:

```
Bob Builder signed in at 3:30pm
Max Power signed in at 3:24pm
...
```

So when I query the last ten entries in SignIn and then call toJSON, I'd like to have the User data for that SignIn record also included in the JSON.

How can I do that?

Note, if there's a better way to do this, I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing about Propel, is that [the documentation](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html) is really clean, very readable and always helpful.

For your request, you can try the following request. Take a closer look at it, it's readable (as always with Propel)

```
$signIn = SignInQuery::create()
  ->select(array('User.firstname', 'User.lastname', 'SignIn.time'))
  ->join('User')
  ->orderByTime('desc')
  ->limit(10)
  ->find()
  ->toJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternate solution: you can also override any of the `*Base` methods in your classes, I've done this many times to add extra info to the `toJSON`, `toArray`, or `fromArray` methods.

In SignIn.php:

```
public function toJSON() {
  $fields = json_decode(parent::toJSON());
  $user = $this->getUser(); // assumes you have a foreign key set up
  $fields->firstname = $user->getFirstname();
  $fields->lastname = $user->getLastname();
  return json_encode($fields);
}
```

Now you just query for your SignIn objects and whenever `toJSON` is called the user data will be appended:

```
$signIn = SignInQuery::create()
  ->orderByTime('desc')
  ->limit(10)
  ->find()
  ->toJson();
```

Note that the `toJSON` override is actually an override of the generic "to[Format]" method in BaseObject which is handled by the code on line 380 (in v1.6): `public function __call($name, $params) { ... }`